# I'm so grateful I'll upvote your unrelated answer

Tags: discussion, upvotes, etiquette

The answer was very helpful. I accept it, I upvote it. I would've upvoted it twice if I could. So I navigate to the user's profile, find another high-vote answer of theirs and upvote that one instead.

Good idea or not?

Comment: bad idea. You vote on the POSTS, not on the USER.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know better.  You shouldn't even need to be asking this.

Comment: If you had phrased this "I think that upvoting questions based on the person who asked them is a bad idea.  What do you think?" you'd have +12 right now.

Comment: Guys, stop down voting him. He's asking a valid question - at least he isn't doing it.

Comment: @Tim Read the very first point of the downvote tooltip.

Comment: @Servy hmm fair point. But there is no duplicate of it afaik.

Comment: @Tim: Check the [When does serial upvoting occur?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/293859) section of this answer on Meta SE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way to say 'thanks' here is to just up-vote the answer, and optionally accept it.

If you're clicking to see a user's profile with the intent of "I need to find something to vote on", it's a pretty good sign that you're misinterpreting the purpose of voting.

Voting should be opportunistic. You see something, it makes sense, it checks out and tests and you say *this is something the site should show as valuable*. When you look at it as *this is something that's probably worth ten rep*, you break the peer-review process a bit.

That's not to say that you shouldn't up-vote great stuff you see from someone if you happen to view their profile in an effort to see what else they've said about a certain topic, but take care to realize that you're focusing on the *user* at that point. Are the questions that they answered also worthy of being more significant on the site? How about competing answers to those questions? Any edits to make while you're looking at it as a whole?

Look at each question page as a single artifact, and curate it as such, if you're going to go digging :)

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not a good idea. You should vote based on a post, not on a user. If you would upvote a specific user's answers/questions too much, your votes will get reversed.

Instead of upvoting many posts of a user if you found one of their answers great, [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on that answer.

Answer (score 3):

The system will detect serial voting and undo all of it. Doing this could result in even the deserved up-vote on the original answer being reversed.